# Universal Tensorflow Wrapper for Model training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to build a tensorflow wrapper to train model. The idea is that you can define your model in a function, pass it to object/wrapper and it will do the rest. So you don't have to code everything from the beginning every time. I will make it clear with some pseudocode

```
def model():
    //Define your tf graph/structure here
    return output
```

And then you will have a class, which you can pass your model, training data, valid data into it

```
class tf_wrapper():
   def __init___(model,training_data,valid_data):
      //init stuffs
   def train():
     //code to train the model
```

The train code should look like some standard one in many tutorial:

```
for i in range(epochs):
    sess.run(feed_dict{placeholder_X: batch_X, placeholder_Y: batchY)
```

What I struggle with right now is, there is different kind of model structure, loss function, input pipeline ... for example: loss function for classification task is different from regression (crossmax entropy vs MSE) also the calculation of accuracy, or the way you input data of CNN is different from RNN. What is the best way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you aware of Keras ? https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html

Comment: Well it doesn't help ... you still have to build everything from the beginning every time use want to train your model. What i want is, something that i could plug my model in and train with the provided data